# Matrices product by using packed storage

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following question, and I hope it won't be off-topic. Within
a MATLAB code I generally have an $N\times N$ symmetric distance
matrix

Distance=\begin{array}{cccccccc}
d_{1,1} & d_{1,2} & ... & ... & ... & ... & d_{1,N-1} & d_{1,N}\\
d_{2,1} & d_{2,2} & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
d_{N-1,1} & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
d_{N,1} & d_{N,2} & ... & ... & ... & ... & d_{N,N-1} & d_{N,N}
\end{array}

Furthermore, a frequency vector is defined

$$ Frequency=(1:2048)*df $$

as well as some other constant parameters.

Then, inside a for loop I perform this

```
for i = 1:2048
 cohC = -12*sqrt((frequency(i)/10)^2 + (0.12/340.2)^2);
 Coherence = Distance*cohC;
 CholeskyLower = chol(Coherence,'lower'); // Cholesky Decomposition
 FFT_terms(:,i) = CholeskyLower*normrnd(0,1,N,1); // The lower triangular factor multiplied by a random vector
end
```

It works fine, but then I decided to store the $Distance$ matrix
with the so-called **packed-storage method**, which consists in the following

```
for i = 1:size(Distance,1)
 for j = 1:i
  k = i + (2*size(Distance,1) - j)*(j - 1)/2;
  packedDistance(k) = Distance(i,j);
 end
end
```

The question is: how to perform a loop such as the first one described,
where I was getting an $FFT_{terms}$ matrix made up of $N\times2048$
elements, but by using the $packedDistance$ matrix?